# Не понимаю как избавиться от ошибки "Оператор "==" невозможно применить к операнду типа "char[]" и "char""

Tags: c#

```
    using System;

namespace Vowel_or_consonant
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Check(string s)
        {
            if (s == "")
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Пустая строка!");
                return;
            }
            else
            {
                char [] vowels = { 'a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u' }; 
                int vCount = 0, cCount = 0;
                for (int i = 0; i < s.Length; i++) 
                {
                    if ((char.ToLower(s[i]) >= 'a') && (char.ToLower(s[i]) <= 'z'))
                    {
                        if (vowels == char.ToLower(s[i]))
                            vCount++;
                        else
                            cCount++;
                    }
                }
                if (vCount > cCount)
                    Console.WriteLine("Гласных больше");
                else if (vCount < cCount)
                    Console.WriteLine("Согласных больше");
                else
                     Console.WriteLine("Количество согласных и гласных одинаково");
                return;
            }
        }
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string a;
            Console.Write("Введите строку: ");
            a = Console.ReadLine();
            Check(a);
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы проверяете на равенство массив и символ.

Не

```
if (vowels == char.ToLower(s[i]))
```

а

```
if (Array.IndexOf<char>(vowels, char.ToLower(s[i])) != -1)
```